# Parsing the data from Socket.IO in the Flash client

Tags: javascript, node.js, actionscript-3, websocket, socket.io

Use on server node.js and module Socket.IO.
Data is sent as follows:

```
  var tests = [555, 777];

  client.send("Test string"); //first message
  client.send({tests:tests}); //second message
```

If this is a text string (first message), then the data is displayed correctly. 
But if it's JSON (second message), it fails to parse of the resulting object.

```
protected function onMessage(event:FlashSocketEvent):void{

txt.text += event.data;  //[object Object]
txt.text += event.data.tests; //undefined
txt.text += event.data['tests'];  //undefined

            }
```

I use https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js and https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for Socket.IO you would use client.send() for plain string messages and try looking into client.emit() to transmit json: [socket.emit vs socket.send](http://groups.google.com/group/socket_io/browse_thread/thread/d94bed347a5df96e)

In particular, the second response says:

> socket.emit allows you to emit custom events on the server and client
>
> socket.send sends messages which are received with the message event

Comment: Thank you vassilo. Is better. If i use client.emit() console log is "debug - flashsocket writing 5:::{"name":{"tests":[555,777]}}." But type 5 is note JSON (4), but event https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec#Encoding and i can not parse this line.

Comment: What is the call that you are making? Try client.emit('Test string', {'tests': tests}). From the documentation it looks like when you call emit your first parameter is a name of your message and the second call should be the json for your message.

Comment: If i call client.emit('Test string', {'tests': tests}), console write "debug - flashsocket writing 5:::{"name":"Test string","args":[{"tests":[555,7
77]}]}". Now I'm just testing a text-chat based on the examples in the links above.

Answer (score 0):

Solve problem added json property

client.json.send